# Deploy certificate to standalone javafx application

Tags: ssl, javafx, javafx-2, ssl-certificate

i am building a JavaFX application which i am intending to distribute in a self-installing/standalone mode.

In some part the application is making some https requests (upload file via https), so i will have to import the certificate into my JDK cacerts file.

However how am i going to use/deploy this certificate into the self-contained final version of my application?